# Deploy Add-ins saved on SharePoint across multiple computers

Tags: excel, sharepoint, add-in

I am looking for a way where I can share a bunch of macros consolidated as an Add-in stored in a workbook that is saved as a .xlsm, with everyone in my department. I need to maintain full control of the workbook being used, so that no one can make changes to it, but if I make changes to the master copy it will automatically update all the ones used by all the people I am sharing it with. A shared drive deploy is out of the question due to access issues.

We are using SharePoint to control access to the workbook. I am wanting to do something similar to what's described in [this link](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment) but using SharePoint instead of a shared drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Workbooks.Open ("http://sharepointaddress/Workbookwithaddins.xlsm")

End Sub
```